# Does Agora.io provides calling feature like whatsapp?

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am working on an application in which I have to add a calling feature like whatsapp. For this feature I found agora.io I went through with it's documentation and found that it has calling features just like meetings. I want a calling feature like whatsapp calling. Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the calling feature to push notification when the app is in background or even closed? You need to integrate with **ConnectionService** for Android or **CallKit** for iOS or **CallKeep** for Flutter and React Native.

ConnectionService: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService

CallKit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit

CallKeep: https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep

Comment: From whatsapp calling, I mean to say when the user click on a call button he will directly call to the client. In agora.io do we have any feature like direct calling because I research on it and I didn't found anything of direct calling it has feature like meeting where one user join the channel only when the host has joined the meeting.

Comment: I have to use the agora calling feature in web application.